# Edit: Solved, Calculus homework: rewriting limit as definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, summation

On my Calculus homework, there is a question that I am having trouble with.

The question is:

Rewrite
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\left[\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{3}+\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{3}+\ldots+\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^3\right]$ as an integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

I know how to do this kind of problems, but this one is a little confusing.

I know that:
$$\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}\\x_i = \Delta x i + a\\\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)\Delta x=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$
and in the question
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{n} &=& \frac{b-a}{n} = \Delta x\\1&=&b-a\\a&=&0\\b&=&1\end{eqnarray*}$$
So the answer must be something like:
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$
What I don't understand is the $f(x_i)$ part.

I don't know how to simplify the expression inside the bracket.

It becomes something like:

$$\left[x^{3}+x^{3}+\ldots+\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{3}\right]$$

I can't figure out what $f(x)$ is.

Any help or explanations are appreciated, thanks.

---

**Edit:**
The question in my homework might have a typo. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that we are evaluate rectangular area $f(x_i)\cdot  \Delta x$, here $x_i = \frac{i}{n}$ and then we sum up the rectangular areas.

$$f(x)=x^3$$

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. But can I ask how did you get $f(x)=x^{3}$ from the summation. I don't understand at all how $\left[\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{3}+\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{3}+\ldots+\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{3}\right]$ simplify into x^3.

Comment: Actually upon closer examination, are you sure the question is not $\sum \frac1n \left( \frac{i}n\right)^3$. You mean there is another summation inside the summation?

Comment: The question is not $\sum \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{3}$. I don't think there is another summation inside the summation. It looks like there is a series inside the summation since there is an ellipsis.

Comment: I've checked the answers from my homework. The correct answer is $f(x)=x^{3}$, but I'm not sure how the answer was found.

Comment: I think there is a typo, the question intended to ask identity $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum \frac1n \left( \frac{i}{n}\right)^3$ as an integral.

Comment: Okay, thank you anyways for your generous help.